# ORA-01722: Numero no valido SQL/Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, eclipse

tengo la siguiente consulta porque llevo un montón de tiempo con ella y es que no logro sacarla:
Uso SQL developer y Eclipse (java y jsp), y tengo lo siguiente:

```
Tabla1: Un valor decimal
mi_valor NUMBER(9,2)
```

En eclipse con sentencias parametrizadas:

```
String mi_valor; (aqui es String).

String query = "update Tabla1 set mi_valor = ?valor";

SentenciaPreparada sp = crearSentencia(query);

sp.ponParametro("valor", mi_valor.replace(".",","); --> Esto es porque en Java lo recogemos como por ejemplo 1.07 pero en SQL tiene que ser 1,07.

sp.ejecutaUpdate();
```

Una vez me funciona, pero luego durante un rato me deja de funcionar y me sale el dichoso `ORA-01722: Numero no valido` y saco por traza la sentencia.
Lo curioso es que esa misma sentencia que me da error, la ejecuto en SQL Developer y me funciona perfectamente, y si pruebo mas adelante me vuelve a funcionar una vez, pero solo una, y luego deja de funcionar...
Por traza lo que saca es `update Tabla1 set mi_valor = '1,07'` , que me funciona perfectamente en el Developer.

Tambien he probado poniendo:
 `update Tabla1 set mi_valor = to_number(replace(?valor,'.',','));`

Pero pasa lo mismo, en SQL developer correctisimo ya que la traza de la sentencia es la misma, y desde la aplicación me funciona una vez si y luego ya no...

Es un ejemplo tonto para no saturar con una tabla grande y un montón de parámetros y trazas, aunque si es necesario lo pongo.

Y también decir que no soy un gran experto en la materia, recientemente he empezado a trabajar con ello.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Como recomendación no traduzcas los nombres de clases y métodos propios del lenguaje.

Comment: Si te refieres a lo de SentenciaPreparada, crearSentencia, ponParametro y eso, en realidad los tienen asi definidos. Gracias por la corrección.

Comment: No entiendo nada. Qué son esas clases en español? Y desde cuándo hay que usar `,` para separar los decimales en SQL? Después las cosas no funcionan como queremos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que tienes un PreparedStatement prueba realizar los siguientes cambios:

La consulta para agregar un valor es INSERT, UPDATE es para actualizar el valor de uno o varios registros.
Consulta SQL: `INSERT INTO Tabla1(mi_valor) VALUES(?)`

PreparedStatement: `sp.setDouble(1, Double.valueOf(mi_valor)) ;`

El número `1` en `setDouble`  significa la primera variable representada por el primer símbolo `?`, de esta forma el `PreparedStatement` se encargara de la correcta Traducción a la hora de insertar el valor numerico.

Como recomendación no manejes los numeros como String ya que es una mala practica.

Comment: Work like a charm!!! muchas gracias!! Tomo nota de los consejos que me habeis dado